# Can the data analytic functions provided by R studio be consumed as a web service

Tags: r, web-services, rstudio, data-analysis

I'm using the R studio to do some data analysis and content evaluation. The R studio provides a wide range of analytics and functions to organise and analyse data set. Can the same functions of the R studio be consumed as a web service rather than using the studio itself?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: R is a statistical programming language for data analysis. RStudio is an IDE for code development in R. I don't think that RStudio provides any analytics functionality, so am I right in assuming that you would basically like to make an R script available as a web API microservice?

Comment: @JanLauGe Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your R-models available over an API, try looking into [OpenCPU](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/opencpu/index.html)

Unlike with notebooks, you won't need to reshare whenever you make any change.
Just host your R-environment on a server and make the endpoint available for consumption over the web. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in the comment R Studio is just IDE. If I understand you correctly you are looking for something like:

- [R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/): easy-to-use interactive R console
- [The Jupyther Notebook](http://jupyter.org/): an open-source web application that allows you to create and share documents that contain live code.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to run R locally, for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much for comment, so I have small present for you. Good luck!